# Automating the Facebook messenger: how to receive elements from chat toolbar?

Tags: facebook, automation, appium-android

I'm trying to write the Appium automation for Facebook Messenger android app, which will send a message to contact, and i can't find the elements of chat toolbar (textbox, "gallery" and "camera" buttons, etc.) using the Appium Desktop 1.6.2: 
[Messenger toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhqfQ.png)

The objects tree that I receive doesn't contain those elements:[Object tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQaPO.png)

I see that there is "parsererror" element at the top of the objects tree - can it be related?
Is there any way to find those toolbar objects or the only way to automate them it to tap by coordinates?

Comment: Facebook’s terms & conditions forbid you from sending messages using such automation to begin with. And I am having a hard time trying to picture any non-spam application for this to begin with.

Comment: I see. I guess i will need to use ugly and unstable workaround to complete my task:
1. Tap on textbox using the coordinates (i will take a percentage of screen's width and height).
2. Input text with ADB command 'adb input text foo'.
3. Tap on "Send" button using the coordinates.

Comment: Which is also not allowed.